# Is there a smart way to simplipy my pixel by pixel value changing code?

Tags: numpy, opencv, python

```
# masking 
masked = mask.copy()
for py in range(0,h):
    for px in range(0,w):
        if masked[py][px][0] != 0:
            masked[py][px] = im[py][px]
masked = cv2.cvtColor(masked, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
```

Is there any fancy way to convert my dirty code to a simple code with cv2 or numpy function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this could help to replace the loop (quite self-explanatory similar to your loop):

```
indices = np.where(masked[:,:,0] != 0)
masked[indices]=im[indices]
```